# Ruby/Rails: Convert a grouped-sum date column into a Unix time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, format

I'm trying to convert a date from this format "YYYY-MM-DD" to a Unix time.

I'm running this code to get grouped sum:

```
Invoice.group('date(filled_at)').sum(:lines_price).to_a
```

Which returns this:

```
[["2012-12-15", #<BigDecimal:b451450,'0.19275E4',18(45)>], ["2012-12-17", #<BigDecimal:b45107c,'0.764235E3',18(45)>]]
```

The problem is that I need to get this data into a chart that accepts this format:

```
[
  [1341014400000, 123.5],
  [1341018000000, 150.3],
  ...
]
```

How do I convert the array to a format that is acceptable by the chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard to convert if it can be parsed:

```
Invoice.group('date(filled_at)').sum(:lines_price).to_a.collect do |date, sum|
  [ DateTime.parse(date).to_i, sum.to_f ]
end
```

The `BigDecimal` is just a way of representing the `NUMERIC` SQL type in Ruby with proper handling of fixed-point values.